# How Do I run UnitTest++ using the command line on Windows

Tags: c++, unit-testing, command-line, unittest++

I'm new at UnitTest++ and  I'm having problems making it work using the command line on windows (I need it to work only using the command line).

I already built the solution and I have the library (UnitTest++.vsnet2005), but when I try to build it it says "UnitTest++.h: No such file or directory".

This is the command that I'm using:
g++ -o TestRowMajor TestRowMajor.cpp -L"C:\Users\myUser\Documents\Proyects\Tools
Tests\UnitTest++\tests\unit" -lUnitTest++

This is the simple code that I'm trying to test, is the one in their [web site](http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/UnitTest++.html)

```
  // test.cpp
 #include <UnitTest++.h>

  TEST(FailSpectacularly)
  {
    CHECK(false);
  }

  int main()
  {
    return UnitTest::RunAllTests();
  }
```

Any help will be really appreciated, thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot find *UnitTest++.h*. So, the first thing you need to do is make sure you can find that file yourself.

Your command line has `-I` option, adding *UnitTest++* to the include path. According to the command line, that's a directory in the same folder as your source file, *TestRowMajor.cpp*. Is that really true? It seems more likely to me that you installed UnitTest++ somewhere else, so you need to specify the *absolute path* in your `-I` option, not a relative path.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I don't know how to install UnitTest++, not sure if it can be installed, what I have understood is that the library has to be generated and then included in the .cpp file, correct me if I'm wrong.

To make it easy I have my .cpp file in te same directory as the library tht I generated with visual studio.

This is more ignorance that anything else, but I've read and can't find the way to do it.

Comment: For most libraries, installing consists of unpacking an archive somewhere, and possibly compiling something. You've done both those steps, so you have installed it. The question is *where*. Find *UnitTest++.h*. If *you* can't find it, then you cannot expect the compiler to find it, either.

Comment: If I place my .cpp file in the same directory where UnitTest++ is it does not give me the previous error, now I get this:
"In file included from UnitTest++.h:6,
                 from TestRowMajor.cpp:4:
Config.h:17: Invalid token in expression
In file included from ExecuteTest.h:5,
                 from TestMacros.h:5,
                 from UnitTest++.h:12,
                 from TestRowMajor.cpp:4:
MemoryOutStream.h:8: sstream: No such file or directory"

I don't know if I should be doing something else or different, because I guess I should not touch or change the existing code.

Comment: First, stop moving your source files around. It makes it sound like you're fumbling around in the dark, trying things until something works, without regard for what you changed or why it worked, and that's not what *learning* is. I asked you to find the file *UnitTest++.h*. When you find it, take the *directory* where that file lives and put that directory in your `-I` option. Then the compiler can find that file, and you can move on.

Comment: Next, if your compiler cannot find a header named *sstream*, then your entire compilation environment is hosed. That's a basic system header, and g++ should have no trouble finding it. The first step to a solution is the same as before, though: Find the file on your system, so that *you* know where it is. The next step is to get the compiler to recognize that same location. But just do things one step at a time.

Comment: OK sorry for the mess, I'll try to follow the steps that you suggested and I'll let you know, thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't understand, @Remian. There's an example of it here in the question, and I explain exactly how to figure out what to use with it. You must elaborate on your question before I can elaborate on my answer.